# How To Set up an Event Handling Using JQuery To Make a Floating Div fade in on Product Row Hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

basically what I would like to do is to set up an event handling using JQuery to detect when the mouse pointer moves over one of my product rows to make a floating div tag fade in containing a link to a site that describes the product.

Link: [www.thetotempole.ca/javascriptproject2.html/](http://thetotempole.ca/javascriptproject2.html)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Arrays</title>

<style>
#tbl img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
          transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

#tbl td:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
}
td {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <center><table id="tbl" border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Description</th>
            <th>Product Images</th>
         </tr>
  </table>
<script>
var products = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    description: "It might be fruit, or it might be an iPhone",
    imageUrl: "images/apple.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Dell",
    description: "Buy this one online at dell.com",
    imageUrl: "images/dell.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "IBM",
    description: "If you want a mainframe they still have some",
    imageUrl: "images/ibm.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Toshiba",
    description: "Get a discount through SAIT (maybe)",
    imageUrl: "images/toshiba.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Atari",
    description: "Try a classic gaming machine",
    imageUrl: "images/atari.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Commodore",
    description: "64k should be enough for anyone",
    imageUrl: "images/commodore.jpg"
  }
];

var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
products.forEach(function(product) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.appendChild(createCell(product.name));
  row.appendChild(createCell(product.description));
  row.appendChild(createImageCell(product.imageUrl));

  table.appendChild(row);
});

function createCell(text) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.innerText = text;
  return cell;
}

function createImageCell(url) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", url);

  var cell = document.createElement("td");  
  cell.appendChild(image);
  return cell;
}
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok, so what's the issue?

Comment: I've looked everywhere to find code similar to mine, and I have no clue how I would add in the divs to my table. Which is why I came to Stack.

Answer (score 1):

Youre gonna have to start by giving each of the row specific ID's or some way to select them with jQuery.

You can do something like this

```
products.forEach(function(product) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.setAttribute("id", "row"+product.name);
  row.appendChild(createCell(product.name));
  row.appendChild(createCell(product.description));
  row.appendChild(createImageCell(product.imageUrl, product.name));    
  table.appendChild(row);

  //This is the part that appends the hover event
  $("#row"+product.name).hover(function(){
      //This is for the mouseenter event so show the div here
  },function(){
      //This is for the mouse out event so youd want to hide the div here
  });
});
```

Comment: How would you hide the div? So far I've created a div underneath the table: "  </table>
  <div id="row"><p>www.apple.com</p></div>
<script>"

Comment: @Kelsey If your ID is row for every div thats gonna be a problem. They must be unique!!! I wouldt suggest making ti something like AppleDiv, DellDiv ect. Once you have that do `$("#"+product.name+"Div").show()` and use `.hide()` in the function section wehre it says to hide it.