# How to Make Tooltip Appear on TD Hover Using JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

having troubles doing this, so thought I'd turn to old Stack to help me out. :) I have my Table already and I want a different Tooltip to appear for each TR when a User hovers over a TD... So say if a User hovers over the Apple name, description, or image I would like a tooltip to appear saying the link to Apple's website.

Link to site: [www.thetotempole.ca](http://thetotempole.ca/javascriptproject2.html)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Arrays</title>

<style>
#apple2 { 

#tbl img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
          transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

#tbl td:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
}
td {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <center><table id="tbl" border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Description</th>
            <th>Product Images</th>
         </tr>
  </table>
<script>
var products = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    description: "It might be fruit, or it might be an iPhone",
    imageUrl: "images/apple.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Dell",
    description: "Buy this one online at dell.com",
    imageUrl: "images/dell.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "IBM",
    description: "If you want a mainframe they still have some",
    imageUrl: "images/ibm.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Toshiba",
    description: "Get a discount through SAIT (maybe)",
    imageUrl: "images/toshiba.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Atari",
    description: "Try a classic gaming machine",
    imageUrl: "images/atari.jpg"
  }, {
    name: "Commodore",
    description: "64k should be enough for anyone",
    imageUrl: "images/commodore.jpg"
  }
];

var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
products.forEach(function(product) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.appendChild(createCell(product.name));
  row.appendChild(createCell(product.description));
  row.appendChild(createImageCell(product.imageUrl));

  table.appendChild(row);
});

function createCell(text) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.innerText = text;
  return cell;
}

function createImageCell(url) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", url);

  var cell = document.createElement("td");  
  cell.appendChild(image);
  return cell;
}

</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what's your problem?

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010464/how-to-set-up-an-event-handling-using-jquery-to-make-a-floating-div-fade-in-on-p

Comment: What's wrong with using the title HTML attribute on every <td> element you want to have a tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

This can be so easily done using jQueryUI's tooltip feature...

All you need is to include both jQuery and jQueryUI in your document `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
```

Then, initialize the tooltips:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( document ).tooltip();
    }); //END $(document).ready()

</script>
```

And finally, add a `title="Text for tooltip"` to the element over which you want tooltip to appear:

```
<a href="#" title="http://apple.ca">Visit the Apple store</a>
```

---

To match with your code, you should be able to do something like this:

```
function createCell(text) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.innerText = text;
  cell.setAttribute("title", "This will be the tooltip for this TD");
  return cell;
}
```

or

```
function createImageCell(url) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", url);
  image.setAttribute("title", "This will be the tooltip for this image");

  var cell = document.createElement("td");  
  cell.appendChild(image);
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thing is, I dont have any elements besides the ones in the Script. How would I add the title to an element in a script? What I really want is to make the tooltips for each Image in the table but I am not sure how to do this... The only thing relevant I can think of would be image.apple.jpg.setAttribute("title", "http://apple.ca"); and that won't even work so I am really stuck here.